# What should be done about offensive names?

Tags: discussion, support, users, offensive

I found this name which I find very offensive, is it allowed?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1641587/fuck-stack-overflow

Comment: What you **should** do, is flag any post by someone like that for moderator attention and explain you are flagging because of the offensive user name.

Comment: It is not the case here but we have to be sensitive to the fact that sometimes a name which is benign or has extremely positive connotations in the language it originates from can sound offensive in another language.

Comment: Grow a thicker skin.

Comment: Keep your skin the same thickness

Comment: Why does it offend you? I realize that the words are vulgar, but we're all adults here, surely you don't let yourself be affected by such things.

Comment: Flagging this post as offensive since it contains the word the OP was offended by.

Comment: @TankorSmash, I dont think that making light, or opressing the feelings of what someone finds offensive is the right tactic here.  This is word that in english culture is well established to be offensive and should be flagged accordingly.

Comment: @TankorSmash I don't think that this particular username is the point. Surely there is _some_ username that we feel is damaging to the community, and we need to have an answer to how we deal with such names.

Comment: @TankorSmash: since when is Stack Overflow an adults-only site?

Comment: @Wooble I should have used 'mature' instead. My point was really that 'sticks and stones' should be the approach to take. Naturally I don't speak for anyone else.

Comment: define offensive....i find that name to be hilarious.

Comment: @DVK sounds dangerous

Comment: First you should prove it's not a real name. It may be harder than it looks.

Comment: As for the arguments coming up in the comments of (paraphrasing) "I don't find it offensive, so why should it be flagged as such?" http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270402/clarify-guidelines-for-flagging-words-or-phrases-we-perceive-to-be-offensive

Comment: The account was already renamed to user-(arbitrary number).

Comment: Can we flag profiles ?

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil no you cant flag a profile, but you can raise a custom flag on any post and state you are using it to flag a user

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Pick out a post by that user (any answer or question will do—not a comment) and flag it for moderator attention. Pick the 'in need of moderator intervention' option and explain that you find the username to be offensive. If there are no posts, you can flag one of your own posts too; the idea is to drop us a message, it's not about the specific post that was flagged.

A moderator will look into it and, if necessary, rename the account.

Profile information gets more leeway when it comes to offensive content (you can swear all you want in your About Me section, provided it's not illegal and overtly racist), but a username is visible everywhere the user posts. As such it is subject to the [terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal), which require that subscriber-provided content is not offensive.

Comment: Classic (and hilarious) example of profanity in the "About me" box: [Welbog](http://stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog)

Comment: worth mentioning that users with no activity (no posts/comments to flag) and  offensive names should somehow be reported - possibly through the [**contact us page**](http://stackoverflow.com/contact)

Comment: *overtly* racist? So I can be covertly racist?

Comment: BTW, I'm not saying I intend to, just seemed an interesting choice of words.

Comment: @Liam: I was trying to head of samples of off-color jokes that some people *might* find racist...

Comment: @mehow: Interestingly enough, if an account has *no activity at all* to flag (no posts, no comments and no suggested edits), their name isn't being plastered all over the site either, just like their 'about me' section. I'd just flag a post of my own in that case, and point to the user account in the 'other' text. Moderators are, as a whole, smart enough to figure out what account I am talking about in that case. Or so one would *hope*, at least. :-)

Comment: @Liam Of course 'covert' racism is fine; anything can be 'covertly racist', if you want it to be; the wages of *that* path are madness--so one is limited, within the bounds of sanity, to obvious or overt racism.

Comment: @Vector Gorgoth: That's covertly racist.

Comment: Related: [flag a user profile - not a post, when the profile is the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217778/flag-offensive-user-profile)

Comment: @BoltClock So is that.

Comment: I believe that every aspect of SO should be strictly G-rated and a no-tolerance approach should be adopted, regardless of the `celebrity status` or intended humour involved. Most of the posts using objectionable language comes from one-time posters thrilled at having learned a four-letter word and exercising their "right" to post without censure. It's disappointing to lack the support of moderators in this respect. Sure, I could edit the material myself, or "discuss it" with the poster. That just achieves their goal; moderator action is required. Gutter language simply shows no imagination.

Comment: who defines what offensive is?

Comment: @magoo thats your opinion...what you find objectionable i find awesome. where you see no imagination i find vividly alive. guess its okay for you to force your views on me though, right?

Comment: Welbog's profile had the rest of the office in stitches. Hilarious. Thank you good sir.

Comment: so what about when someone starts asking questions about the use of an api on an adult site? completely appropriate, professional and one of the most lucrative business models on the itnernets

Comment: @John does that require using an offensive username, does it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i am sorry i wasn't directing that at you i should of used correct syntax

Comment: Late reply, but a quick search using the F-word returns 48 results. Is there anything we can do about it except from flagging them one by one?

Comment: @MartijnPieters what if a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8782974/dimitri-cyka-blyat?tab=profile) has no posts on the site? This user had an offensive post, which was removed, but the user still exists.

Comment: @JessedeBruijne: if there are no posts you can reach to flag, find *a* post (your own perhaps) and flag that, and point to the account. I deleted that account, all it was used for was to troll.

Comment: I think it would go a long way to edit your solution to include content if the user does not have any visible posts (ie. Flag one of your own posts).

Comment: @FrankerZ: done.

Answer (score 8):

If the user doesn't have any visible posts, then you could do what you've done here and post a question on meta.

Reference this question/answer to make it clear that your new question is not a duplicate but a request for the name to be reset.

Though please don't go looking for such accounts (there are [72](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all&search=fuck) at the time of writing), only flag the ones you come across in your normal usage of the site.

If you don't want to make it public then you could flag one of your own posts [thanks PeterJ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251682/what-should-be-done-about-offensive-names/370197?noredirect=1#comment604168_370197) with the "other" option with a link to the profile and a brief explanation. However, it might take us a while to get round to this (depending on the size of the flag queue) and it might take some of us a while to work out why you've flagged one of your own posts :)

Comment: What if there are many users with offensive keywords in their names? Apparently [there are 72](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all&search=fuck).

Comment: @AJ - see my edit ;)

Comment: Is a meta post really necessary, I always thought it was OK to flag say a post of your own and explain it doesn't relate to that post and include a link to the profile?

Comment: @PeterJ - That would work, but it might take me a moment or two to work out why you'd flagged your own post ;)

Comment: @ChrisF What if I said "I'm flagging this because this user has no posts to flag"?