# How do you flag an offensive username when the user has no posts?

Tags: discussion, moderation, rude-or-abusive

We just deleted a rude answer in SOCVR, but the user also made his name rude as well.

Since the post was already flagged as spam I couldn't also mod flag it. And there's no way to flag his profile, and he had no other answers, there wasn't an obvious way to alert a mod. Thankfully a lurking mod in chat nuked it, but how do we deal with this in the future?

Comment: The title should match the situation described in the question imo

Comment: @Pekka웃 Expanded it a bit more

Comment: flag the question they answered and in flag message use link to their answer to refer moderator to it. Easy peasy, I sometimes flag question to point mods to answers, last time it was yesterday, worked like a charm

Comment: Custom flag one of your own posts and explain the problem.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be problematic? There are many ways to get the attention of mods or the team. The contact us form, finding them in chat, flagging your own post as Robert notes, posting on meta as support (not ideal). This situation seems to be resolved though, I am voting to close as no repro.

Comment: If the user has no posts, someone would have to *deliberately* search for the offensive username in 99% of cases. I can't see that this is a problem.

Comment: pinging a mod in chat seems to have been effective, what's wrong with that? it's a rare occurrence, you've just gotta get mod attention in one way or another, either through a chat ping, flagging one of your own posts, contact us page, whatever. Chat ping seems easiest, if you're in a chat room frequented by mods.

Comment: @hichris123: Just because no-one might see it, doesn't mean it's okay.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill This isn't a dupe because my question is about when the user has no valid posts to flag (in which case the path is obvious)

Comment: @Cerbrus Sure, it's not okay, but there's no use in having the account deleted. By bringing it to moderator attention, it'd just be wasting your time and moderator time. This is pretty similar to the spammer zombie accounts: there's a bunch out there, but flagging them all for deletion would have very little net gain to the site.

Comment: @hichris123: getting rid of spammers and trolls is _never not productive_. It's not like it takes a significant amount of effort. Seriously, there is **no excuse** not to flag accounts like that when you see them. Ask any mod on here. I'm sure they'll agree.

Comment: @Cerbrus When there's no posts, there's no reason. SpamRam already takes into account spam/offensive flagged posts for blocking penalties; there's no need to delete accounts for that. Theoretically, the accounts should be autodeleted (eventually) anyway. If an account is just sitting there, doing nothing, there's no point in deleting it. If it is, good; if it's not, oh well.

Comment: @hichris123: You're aware mods can just reset usernames, right? What possible reason is there not to flag an account with a bad username?

Comment: Because there are better things to do with your, my, and moderator's time, @Cerbrus? Again, if a user has no posts, *someone has to search for that user to see the offensive content*. Might as well spend time moderating content that at least one user will see...

Comment: @hichris123: Straw man. There's ___always___ better things to do than enforcing site rules.

Comment: If you'd like to discuss this, @Cerbrus, you can pop into [the Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) -- we're quickly cluttering up the comments here.

Comment: Wouldn't this question apply to all of SE?

Comment: @j08691 [Users Can Report Bugs On Whatever Child Meta Site Suits Them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250152/users-can-report-bugs-on-whatever-child-meta-site-suits-them). That applies to discussions too.

Comment: @hichris123 I don't understand what your point it. I;m just saying that this could be posted on http://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And my point was that it's perfectly fine here or on mSE. Either works, @j08691.

Comment: close voted as dupe since [the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251684/4826457) is edited to include the scenario

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's some options, in order of (my personal) preference:

- If the question isn't deleted yet, flag that, explaining the situation.
- Ask a 10k+ user in chat to flag the deleted Q/A.
- Flag one of your own posts, explaining the situation.
- Ping a mod in chat. (Although this isn't always appreciated. They've got plenty to do already)
- Start a meta thread about the user. (Which gives him a lot of attention: BAD)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't link his user profile for that reason. The other thread's offensive name will live on forever...

Comment: I'll be the sacrificial pingee. My inbox is usually small in the morning anyway, I don't have any issues with chat pings (as a last-resort) on this kind of stuff.