# How should bot accounts flooding documentation with rubbish be handled?

Tags: discussion, documentation, flags, spam

Over the last couple days, the C# documentation (and I'd wager other tags) have been hit by a bot continually making topic requests.

The topic requests consist of a random title (possibly a tag?) and 3 question titles found under C#.

Here's an example of the recent round of requests:

> **List**
>   How to properly compare lists. Stuck with BinaryExpression in C#. Is this using of dictionary thread-safe or not?
>
> **Class**
>   Partial declarations must not specify different base classes?. Derived class > forcing property to be written into initializecomponent. C# Percent encode ? to %C3%A5 based on RFC 5849 OAuth 1.0
>
> **XML**
>   Generate XmlWriter c# code from XML. Saving HTML Table as xml or json. Choosing One table among two tables on the basis of some attribute value in MVC3 and EF

This question is somewhat related to [How to report users spamming in Documentation requests?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339215/how-to-report-users-spamming-in-documentation-requests), but not entirely.

Here's the problem. These requests do not immediately stand out as abusive and/or spam posts. The topic request for `List` could easily be mistaken for a user not making themselves clear, or accidentally requesting a topic rather than asking a question. This means a moderator may view a flag, misidentify it as an honest user making a mistake (or a valid request altogether if they're unfamiliar with the tag) and decline the spam flag.

I've been raising custom moderator flags, but that takes more effort on behalf of myself (finding their profile, explaining the problem) as well as the moderator (reading the flag, checking the profile, reading the requests).

So what's the correct procedure here?

Should I continue with custom flagging, or should I simply flag the request as spam/offensive and hope the moderator is aware of the new deluge of rubbish requests?

Comment: Unless I've been missing something all this time, flagging documentation requests as spam/ offensive does not appear in any moderator queue. I'm not sure what exposure it has to employees, however. Until I stand corrected, I recommend continuing to custom flag of one of the users posts.

Comment: @Matt yeah, that approach seems fine. During the spam floods in Documentation we pinged Shog9 who ran a client-side script to kill things. Mods could only act once the accounts were flagged by us.

Comment: These problems have been reported already a while ago.  They are not getting addressed.  A hint that SE has lost faith in the project as well.  There needs to be an acceptable exit strategy and that's a hard sell, massive amounts of energy will be destroyed.  So *not* handling the spam and let everybody see that the maintenance isn't worth it is a possibly valid approach.

Comment: @HansPassant The last wave of spam had us hook up blacklists and SpamRam (automatic IP blocking based on signal from Q&A and Docs). More to come as well (see my answer). I'll agree that it's reactionary and we should've had all that in the first place, but I wouldn't say these problems "are not getting addressed".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We're putting together plans for outright flagging spam and abusive content. Coming to production hopefully in the next month or so.

"Dismissing" the request as spam or offensive in the meantime *will* feed into SpamRam (an automated system we have that ultimately throttles and blocks source IPs ranges that bring us trouble) and hopefully help slow the flood of garbage.

Flagging a user's post (if any) is also an option, as Matt mentioned in the comments.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if the user hasn't made any posts on SO Main to flag, I've seen mods approve of flagging one of your own posts in order to direct mods to the problem with a link.

Comment: @4castle I think [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332826/4639281) is what you're referring to.