# Allow users to raise custom mod flags outside of Q&As

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page

I would want to raise a flag when a user violates Site Guidelines using inappropriate usernames, profile pictures, targeted hate speech on their *About Me*, and so on.

### The obvious solution would be to raise a flag on one of their questions/answers. But what if the user has none?

For example, take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7574782/fuck) user. Thy have absolutely no activity on their profile. Does that give them a free pass to violate Site Guidelines with an inappropriate Username? There are hundreds of such profiles that need pruning.

What can we do about this?

---

Responding to advice from  [How do you flag an offensive username when the user has no posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332808/how-do-you-flag-an-offensive-username-when-the-user-has-no-posts):

#### 1. If the question isn't deleted yet, flag that, explaining the situation.

Counter: There may not be a question to begin with.

#### 2. Ask a 10k+ user in chat to flag the deleted Q/A.

Counter: View point 1

#### 3. Flag one of your own posts, explaining the situation.

Counter: View point 2 (unless you mean flag any random post of mine in general which is a possibility... but is it the best option?)

#### 4. Ping a mod in chat. (Although this isn't always appreciated. They've got plenty to do already)

Counter: This is an option but will you ping a mod for every such situation?

#### 5. Start a meta thread about the user. (Which gives him a lot of attention: BAD)

Counter: Witchhunting is bad in general, and serves no purpose for profiles like this.

Comment: [How do you flag an offensive username when the user has no posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332808/how-do-you-flag-an-offensive-username-when-the-user-has-no-posts)

Comment: @Pang Countered.

Comment: _"There are hundreds of such profiles that need pruning."_ Why, exactly? They don't show up anywhere.

Comment: Why not simply block such words in usernames?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> (unless you mean flag any random post of mine in general which is a possibility... but is it the best option?)

It is the only option and it doesn't even need to be a post of your own, any post will do that is not locked. As long as you include a link to the post/profile/wiki/chat for the real issue and explain clearly the context.

I have done that only a couple of times and all of those worked out. I admit it feels a bit counter intuitive but *abusing* a post for flagging this way doesn't require 6 to 8 weeks of dev time to add a link somewhere and make it do something useful.

> Ping a mod in chat. (Although this isn't always appreciated. They've got plenty to do already)

That is right. In SOCVR we have the rule that you don't ping a mod to bring *your* flag  to the front of the flag queue .... but some chat rooms, like SOCVR, have the mods lurking. Here is an ultimate example how not to use that [option](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=38766897#38766897) (sorry Nathan) but here is one of [mine, that kind of worked as intended](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=37944739#37944739)

**tl;dr** I don't think we need extra features to facilitate flagging of content/actons that are not (on) questions/answers. And if we do the user profile should be the last in my opinion. Wiki's (plagiarism) and Reviews (robo-clickers) are more prominent candidates to have a shortcut to raise a flag.

Comment: Just to note in the case of rude/abusive usernames or profiles - if they've never posted no one will come across that profile anyway using the site normally so it's not really a problem per se. Once it becomes visible publicly where it is an issue then that'd be via posting something at which point you have a flag target and mods an indicator they are willing to use/get their profile seen etc... I don't see much benefit to what is effectively pre-empting a problem until there is one which can get handled already.

Comment: @JonClements I partly agree. On the internet there are no secrets and if you're looking for trouble, you'll find it. I think we both know the scenario where users post and delete. That kind of behavioral patterns warrant a flag and would justify having the feature. But for the few random abusive/rude profiles that turn-up in a google/SEDE search and are off limits, meh.

Comment: Given that you have to type in the offensive profile name for it to come up in a search…you basically have no right to complain that a match was found for a string *you* typed in. And yeah, while pinging in chat can be done respectfully, this really isn't the best choice because *any* mod can handle one of these situations. No reason to wait for me, or Bhargav, or whomever. Just raise a flag and the next guy/gal on deck can handle it.