# Declined flag for offensive username

Tags: support, declined-flags, moderation, display-names, specific-user

I flagged a post of a user with an offensive user name, following the procedure here: [What should be done about offensive names?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251682/what-should-be-done-about-offensive-names). It ended up declined.

How can I appeal that declination?

Answer (score 20):

You *did not* follow [the procedure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251684). The procedure is to flag one of the user's **posts** (i.e., a question or answer, as Martijn says in his answer).

You flagged a comment. A flag on a comment always and exclusively means, "this comment needs to be deleted". The *reason* that the comment should be deleted is the flag reason, which could be any of "no longer needed", "unfriendly or unkind", "harassment, bigotry, or abuse", or whatever custom reason the flagger enters.

The comment you flagged should not be deleted because it conveyed useful and relevant information, so your comment flag was correctly declined.

If you want action taken on a post or user, you need to flag a post with the "in need of moderator intervention" reason.

(I've now handled the inappropriate user name. Therefore, you don't need to flag it again.)

Comment: lets clarify that on that other post. its not obvious - i used the custom intervention box on the comment - i thought that was treated with a different light.

Comment: No, a custom reason for a comment flag just lets you provide details about why you think the comment needs to be deleted. All comment flags result in the same potential outcomes: helpful => comment deleted; declined => comment preserved. We don't even have a way to give feedback to the flagger when declining comment flags, that's why you only saw "Declined" in the flag history.

Comment: Out of curiosity: is it required to flag posts for mods to use the existing tools in such case (i.e. they don't work when a comment has been flagged) or does one need to flag a post just because it is "procedure" and there is no other real reason?

Comment: Theoretically, @Tom, a moderator *could* see the comment flag, realize that the user was flagging to request something other than deletion of the comment, and then either (A) decline the comment flag (thus preserving the cmnt) but go ahead and take the other necessary action, or (B) delete the flagged cmnt (thus marking the flag as helpful), undelete the cmnt, then go ahead and take the other necessary action. But… in practice, this is not the way it works. Cmnt flags are processed very quickly, deciding whether or not the comment needs to be deleted. That's what a cmnt flag means: delete it.

Comment: @CodyGray So it is like is thought, the tools aren't there to provide proper support via post and comment flag for this situation. Ok. Not ideal, but nothing that will change in the near future, as we both know SO.

Comment: @Tom No. Cody explained both system and moderator handling *differences* between post flags and comment flags. Comment flags can *only* be resolved as explicitly declined or marked helpful by deleting or editing the comment (with or without moderator involvement). There are no other ways for comment flags to be "handled". OTOH, post flags can be explicitly marked helpful or declined by moderators, but are also marked helpful/disputed/declined by the system under some other conditions. Custom post flags survive almost all non-moderator initiated actions, so are actually seen by moderators.

Comment: @Makyen How is that different to what I wrote? Mods can't mark comments as helpful while keeping the comment and doing what the flagger actually wants them to do. Therefore the tools aren't there to handle this situation (i.e. non-post/comment related task) equally for flagged posts and comments.

Comment: I read your earlier comment as saying that neither post flags nor comment flags are reasonable to be used. But, there's a clear, defined procedure for handling this sort of situation, which is to raise an "in need of moderator intervention" *post* flag that explains what the issue is that you see (i.e. the generic directions for any issue not covered by a named flag). Preferably that "in need of moderator intervention" flag will be on a post by the user, but the flag can be on *any* post (suggested to be on your own post, if not that user's post), as long as you explain the actual issue.

Comment: Also note there are a metric <expletive deleted>ton of flags every day. An extra-ordinary flag probably isn't going to get extra-ordinary attention. The server would run out of room in the flag table.